# How to bind_param year and date type?

Tags: php, html, mysql, types

For example, binding varchar type will be 's' and integer type will be 'i'.

However, how do I bind year() and date?

example,

```
$query->bind_param('si??'),$username,$price,$year,$date);
```

Comment: Could you provide query example?

Comment: use same `s` to bind

Comment: ahh so binding date and year would be using 's'.. thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use date & year using `bind_param` this way,

```
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare('insert into your_table (date,year) values (?,?)');
$date = '2015-02-08 12:06:00';
$year='2015'
$stmt->bind_param('s', $date);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $year);
```